# How can i make my grades sort from highest to lowest and viceversa

Tags: ruby-on-rails

(Thats on grade controller.erb)

```
def index
  @grades = Grade.order(params[:sort] + '' + params[:direction])
end
```

(index.html)

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th><%= link_to "Student", :sort =>" grade.student_id"%> </th>
    <th><%= link_to "Student name", :sort => "grade.student_name"%></th>
    <th><%= link_to "Student grade", :sort => "grade.student_grade"%></th>
    <th colspan="3"></th>
  </tr>
```

Comment: suggest you format your code using stack overflow's formatting for code snippets, it looks as if your index.html code is not being properly formatted so we can't see what you really have. Escape ruby code blocks with four ` (backtick) characters before and after on a new line.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your order doesn't work is that you don't have a space between the column and direction - so you're getting `grade.student_gradedesc` - and also your table is most likely named `grades` and not `grade`. What's worse though is that the code creates a SQL injection vulnerability since the string is inserted directly into the query and not quoted.

Instead pass a hash and validate the user input:

```ruby
class GradesController

  def index
    @grades = Grades.all
    if valid_sorting?
      direction = valid_direction? ? params[:direction] : :desc
      @grades = @grades.order(params[:sort] => direction)
    end
  end

  private

  # you shouldn't blindly trust that the user passes data that can be used 
  # in a query
  def valid_direction?
    ["asc", "desc", "ASC", "DESC"].include?(params[:direction])
  end

  def valid_sorting?
    Grades.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) 
  end
end
```

```erb
<th><%= link_to "Student", sort: "student_id" %> </th>
<th><%= link_to "Student name", sort: "student_name" %></th>
<th><%= link_to "Student grade", sort: "student_grade" %></th>
```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev oops. I meant to use order instead of where...

Comment: If you really want to include the table in the "sort" parameter you should split it and validate each part. But YAGNI.